# Как ограничить JVM по кол-ву CPU в Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm

Есть какой-то сервер к примеру с 16 CPU.
Есть JVM (OpenJDK 8u), запускаемая на нем.
Требуется ограничить JVM работой на 4 CPU.
Docker-ы не предлагать, этот доп. ПО, которое необходимо ставить на хост.

Напрашивается механизм с использованием taskset, и в данном случае можно посадить уже имеющиеся треды на какие-то CPU в кол-ве 4 шт.

Но **вновь создаваемые** треды, планировщик ОС будет распределять по всем доступным  CPU и то, что мы ранее ограничили с помощью taskset, для новых тредов не будет актуально. Выполнив Runtime.availableProcessors() мы увидим не 4 CPU, а 16.

Просьба подсказать, кто уже решал подобные задачи по ограничению.

Comment: Была как то такая задача, в итоге развернул на сервере виртуальную машину, которую посадил на нужное количество ядер и внутри виртуальной машины уже крутилась JVM без ограничений.

Comment: если запускать програмку через taskset, а не выставлять привязку сбоку?

Comment: это служба или пользовательское приложение?

Comment: да простой JBOSS сервер стартует. Конкретно WIldFly реализация. Запускается sh сриптом.   Мне не понятно, можно ли как-то указать, что все вновь создаваемые трэды этой JVM должны планироваться на такие же CPU.

Answer (score 3):

@eri был прав.Спасибо.

Дополню для поколений.

Нужно не уже запущенному jvm процессу выставлять cpu affinity с помощью taskset, а запускать jvm используя   taskset.

Пример: 
/usr/bin/taskset -c 5,6,7 java -jar .......

Запустит JVM только на ядрах 5,6,7 

Проверить можно через:
taskset -cp PID_JVM
А лучше увидеть в динамике последний используемый CPU тредом можно так:
top -H -p PID_JVM
покажет все треды
и далее
Shift + F и выбрать "Last Used CPU(SMP)"
Покажет столбец и на каком CPU работал трэд.

Ну и в JVM,  к примеру в  debug-е, тоже покажет верное кол-во видимых CPU:
 Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
 3

Проверял в том числе на JBOSS.